# Determine whether a specific entry has any children in a hierarchical database

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchy, recursive-query

I'm working on a recursive query for a hierarchal table in psql. While I'm able to produce an ordered, hierarchal list, I cannot figure out how to determine whether a parent has any children.

My code at the moment:

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS (
  SELECT h, 1 AS level, ARRAY[ordering] AS ordered_path, ARRAY[id] AS breadcrumb
  FROM report h
  WHERE parent IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT hi, q.level + 1 AS level, ordered_path || ordering, breadcrumb || id FROM q
  JOIN report hi ON hi.parent = (q.h).id )
SELECT (q.h).id, (q.h).parent, (q.h).name, array_to_json(breadcrumb) AS breadcrumbs,
  row_number() OVER (order by ordered_path) AS flat_order
FROM q
ORDER BY ordered_path
```

Which produces the following table:

```
id  | parent |           name        | ordering |    trail     | rownum 
----+--------+-----------------------+----------+--------------+--------
  1 |        | Entry 1               |        1 | [1]          |      1
  2 |      1 | Entry 2               |        1 | [1,2]        |      2
 15 |      2 | Entry 3               |        1 | [1,2,15]     |      3
159 |      2 | Entry 4               |        2 | [1,2,159]    |      4
 16 |      2 | Entry 5               |        3 | [1,2,16]     |      5
```

Essentially, I'd like a column that shows if a specific entry has any children.  In this example, Entry 5 has no children.

The format of the original table is:

```
id  |                        name              |  type   | parent | ordering 
-----+-----------------------------------------+---------+--------+----------
186 | Entry 1                                  | page    |    172 |       23
154 | Entry 2                                  | page    |     63 |        3
169 | Entry 3                                  | page    |    163 |        3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do entries 3 and 4 have no children, in contrast with 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery as an extra field:

```
exists (select 1 from report where parent = q.id) as has_children
```

It's not necessarily the most efficient — though tbh, given the query, I'm can't think of anything better off the top of my head. But it'll work.

Comment: interesting - i wonder how much of a performance hit i'll take. granted, this is a table of contents - at most 100 entries, so it shouldn't really be an issue. where in the query would i place this?

Comment: As late as possible (i.e. after `row_number()` in your example). If you're only selecting a handful of rows, it'll perform OK. If not, look into Guatam's answer. It'll probably yield a merge join plan, but it should be faster if you give Postgres plenty of workmem (to avoid swapping).

Comment: Hmm, I added the subquery after row_number() but don't seem to see anything

Comment: ah, yes - performance isn't an issue, but i'm actually getting inverse results (e.g. those with children are marked as f and those without children are marked t).

Comment: (Double oops. Remove the not like I did in my edit.)

Answer (score 0):

sql  below fill find the child and will count you can change how you want the output by using case statements I tested the code, seems to be working

```
select x.Col1, count(y.Col1) as child from Table1 x
inner join Table2 y on x.Col1 = y.Col1
group by x.Col1
```

Comment: Technically correct, but I'd expect this one to generate a giant merge join on the entire table. (Not saying the nested loop over the entire table that I'd expect from my own answer is any better, mind you; just that we're discussing which of the getting plague or cholera is preferable.)